# How to get ref x, y position in functional component in react-native?

Tags: scrollview, react-functional-component, use-ref, react-native-textinput

I want to get the x, y position when the text cursor is focused on TextInput.

how to get ref position?

here is my code

```
const Code = () => {
  const emailInput = useRef();
  const scrollViewRef = useRef();

  const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');


  const scrollToEmail = () => {
// I want to scroll the y position of the scroll to the center where the TextInput's cursor is focused.
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1}}>
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled" ref ={scrollViewRef}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled behavior={'padding'}>
     
          <TextInput
            ref={emailInput}
            value={email}
            returnKeyType="done"
            onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
            onFocus = {() => scrollToEmail()} <== function works here!
          />

        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </ScrollView>

    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Code;
```

i tried this

1.

```
const handler = findNodeHandle(emailInput.current); 
  console.log(
    emailInput.measure(handler, (x, y, width, height) => {
      console.log(y);
    }),
    ); <== TypeError: emailInput.measure is not a function
```

2. 

```
const handler = findNodeHandle(emailInput.current); 
  console.log(emailInput.current.getBoundingClientRect()); <== TypeError: emailInput.current.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
```

there is no way get the ref's postition in a functional component?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onLayout` prop on the ScrollView to the the height, width, X and Y value.

If you want to use the `ref`, you have to set or console.log the X and Y value on a `useLayoutEffect`. This is because you need to wait for the component to be rendered and "drawn" before you get the information, otherwise you will get only 0

Comment: i tryied onLayout  but, onLayout catches the x,y of the parent component. If you have two TextInputs, onLayout is not very helpful.